# Changing Levels for ResourcePool in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model where my resourcepool(Workers) are in the 1st level in office, and the workstation is on ground floor. So when the agent seizes the resourcepool, the workers seem to float and go to ground floor randomly.

Is there a way to solve this issue? Below is a screenshot of the model

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a Preparation flow chart via a `ResourceTaskStart` that tells the seized resources to do something *before* actually being used by the seizing aagent.

In your case, they should move to an elevator and get to the seizing agent (or vice versa).

See https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/resourcetaskstart.html